# Does flash scale pixel width and height by percent for fullscreen?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen, scale

How does flash scale for fullscreen?

For example, if I draw a shape and give it a width and height of 100px (square)...does that scale up proportionally when the flash is made full screen? Or does that object stay 100px x 100px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will do either depending on the value of `stage.scaleMode`

From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState):

> The scaling behavior of the movie in
>   full-screen mode is determined by the
>   scaleMode setting (set using the
>   Stage.scaleMode property or the SWF
>   file's embed tag settings in the HTML
>   file). If the scaleMode property is
>   set to noScale while the application
>   transitions to full-screen mode, the
>   Stage width and height properties are
>   updated, and the Stage dispatches a
>   resize event. If any other scale mode
>   is set, the stage and its contents are
>   scaled to fill the new screen
>   dimensions. The Stage object retains
>   its original width and height values
>   and does not dispatch a resize event.

Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

It does scale perfectly. Check [this](http://www.mapsofwar.com/images/Religion.swf) , with different sizes of your browser window...